# How to get nested group name from groups in AD using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory, windows-scripting

I have a problem need to example in Active Directory using powershell get all groups that are part of a group and so on recursively.

So if you have group A that has B and B has C Than I need the names of those groups including A.

Also how to fix the following if C also has A I don't want it going in to infinite loop.

Here's my code so far.

```
$groupname = "a","b","c"

foreach($grouphp in groupname)
{
$groupname += (get-adgroupmember -server $domain -identity $grouphp | where-object {$_.objectclass -like "group"}).name
```

}

This will add them in to $groupname 1 level also gives me errors if group is not found and if groups found are also groups I'm looking for it will list them multiple times.

Any-help is appreciated.

Comment: In order to get group inside groups you have to use get-adgroupmember command.

Comment: Yes group names nested in each group. But also make sure it doesn't go to a loop if same groups is found.

Comment: So a single list of all groups is fine? In your example would be a list with a b and c. Or do you need to differentiate the top level vs children?

Comment: No need as long as I have all of them at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below script to get users from nested groups :

```
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-nested-group-15f725f2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list to keep track and then only add if they weren't added previously.

```
$groupname = "a","b","c"

$grouplist = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

foreach($group in $groupname)
{
    if($group -notin $grouplist){$grouplist.Add($group)}

    Get-ADGroupMember -server $domain -Identity $group |
        Where-Object objectclass -like "group" | ForEach-Object {
            if($_.name -notin $grouplist){$grouplist.Add($_.name)}
    }
}

$grouplist
```

Comment: thanks, need to use something else. grouplist doesn;t work with my version of powershell. Method invocation failed.

Comment: What version? I edited, see if this one works.

Comment: Thanks It worked just don't understand why 1 of the groups was repeated 6 times.

Comment: In my example? It shouldn't have been.